# Transfer Files from EC2 Windows Instance to Local Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I need to transfer files from EC2 windows instance to my local machine - which is macbook pro. I am aware that I can scp the files from EC2 windows instance using .pem file but unfortunately we dont have key file. However I have the username and pwd - that can be used to login into the EC2 windows machine. Currently I use Microsoft Remote Desktop app to login into the EC2 windows machine using the above said username and pwd.

Can someone help me how can I download the file from Windows EC2 instance to my mac? Please assist.

Thanks.

Vasanth

Comment: If the file is not very large, you can use S3

Comment: To use the S3 from the EC2 instance we need to make a lot of permissions/setups so we dont want to go into the option. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it needs much except a IAM users with S3 policy and an S3 bucket. Things can get simpler with the pem key but unfortunately, we can use it. 
Maybe you can try to wait for another answer

Answer (score 0):

with Microsoft Remote Desktop on your mac, you can mount up a shared drive & even just copy and paste directory from your Windows EC2 box to your local using CMD+C & CMD+V.

Also, AWS CLI can be installed and used. Upload the S3 file and download the same from your mac. Make sure the AWS account can be accessed.